# outlook style ribbon for web

Tags: asp.net, user-interface

I'm developing a new asp.net website (framework 4.0).
I would like to find an outlook ribbon for web. Until today i saw it only for winforms but not for web.
Does anyone knows of a good ribbon control for web?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be what you want.  It's not free though.

http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/ribbonbar.aspx

Update: A google for 'asp.net ribbon' brings http://aspnetribbon.codeplex.com/ back as the top result and it's open-source.

Comment: Perfect! 2nd one is very nice.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 free component:

1. [Office Web.UI](http://www.officewebui.com/)
2. [ASP.NET Ribbon](http://aspnetribbon.codeplex.com/)

Check them